# JQuery position in the middle of current screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery dialog like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="comments_dialog">
   Insert a comment
   <form>
     <input type="text" id="search" name="q">
   </form>
  </div>
....
</body>



dialog = $( "#comment_dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      dialogClass: "flora",
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "New Comment": addComment,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });
```

My page is a scrollable page with a lot of data.

The issue is that the dialog is being displayed in the middle of the page, and I would like it to be displayed in the middle of the CURRENT screen, so the user wouldn't need to scroll to see it.

How can I do it?

**EDITED**

Based on a few solutions here, I set the CSS to be fixed like this:

```
.flora.ui-front {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
     position:fixed !important;
}
.flora.ui-dialog {
    z-index: 1001 !important;
     position:fixed !important;
}
```

However, I read that position fixed conflicts with zIndex.
What can I do in this case that I need the dialog to put ontop and in the middle of current screen?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: I saw, it but not sure how to locate it like fixed position

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dialog = $( "#comment_dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: window,
      z-index : 9999,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "New Comment": addComment,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `position:absolute;` in your css, try changing it to `position:fixed;`

```
#comment_dialog{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: can I do it inside the js?

Comment: yes.. try
`$("#comment_dialog").css("position":"fixed");`

It will assign a inline CSS to your element. It should work.

Comment: It is either `$("#comment_dialog").css("position","fixed")` or `$("#comment_dialog").css("{position":"fixed}");`

Comment: it doesn't help for jquery dialog

Comment: yes. that helped. but it conflicts with z-Index that I added as well. trying to figure out why

Comment: what's the problem in z-index. It can be managed with css only i guess.

Comment: the poup is not being displayed ontop of the other elements if I don't set the z-Index

Comment: set the z-index with !important in css.

Answer (score 0):

What i always use for my modals / dialogs:

```
#comment_dialog{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

As long as your div has a size (doesn't need to be a fixed size) it will display it in the middle of the window (centered horizontally and vertically)

To apply these styles dynamically to your element with Jquery, use this:

```
$("#comment_dialog").css({
    "position" : "fixed",
    "top": "0",
    "left": "0",
    "right": "0",
    "bottom": "0"

});
```

Comment: Well i would advise to have a css class for this, but if you want to have it inside the js i'll edit my response with it

Comment: it doesn't help. seems like jquery wraps it in another div . I am trying to figure out which one

Comment: well i guess you can also add a `z-index : 9999999` that should avoid any conflicts :D

Answer (score 0):

do a position fixed, and use calc function for top and left

```
#comment_dialog {
  position:fixed;
  left: calc(50% - 200px) !important;
  top: calc(50% - 175px) !important;
}
```

i think that's help for you

Comment: it doesn't help. seems like jquery wraps it in another div . I am trying to figure out which one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS.

Please run the example in "Full Screen" and resize browser window to see the effect.

Explanation:

- Use `position:fixed` for your dialog, this means dialog element is positioned relative to the browser window.
- Set position top and left using `calc` which enable to perform calculations to determine CSS property values.
- Value for top is calculated as: 50% of the actual viewport height minus  half dialog height, so dialog will be always placed in the center of the view port height.
- Value for left is calculated as: 50% of the actual viewport width minus half dialog width, so dialog will be always placed in the center of the view port width.
- Result is the dialog always placed at the center of the viewport.

```css
#comments_dialog {
  position:fixed;
  top: calc(50vh - 250px/2);
  left: calc(50vw - 350px/2);
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="comments_dialog">
  Your content here.
</div>
```

You can have the same result using jQuery in this way, it will add inline style to your dialog:

```
$("#comments_dialog").css({
  "position": "fixed",
  "top": "calc(50vh - 250px/2)",
  "left": "calc(50vw - 350px/2)",
  "width": "350px",
  "height": "250px",
  "background-color": "yellow",
  "z-index": "1000";
});
```

Comment: it doesn't help. seems like jquery wraps it in another div . I am trying to figure out which one

Comment: @Dejell I have made an edit to my answer, to solve any possible issue with z-index, please set z-index for your dialog to a highest value, in my answer 1000. Please let me know if my answer solved your problem thanks!

Comment: hi, no, because zIndex conflicts with div:fixed :(

Comment: @Dejell if you do not want to use z-index, just add markup for your dialog as last item before your </body> tag